# Ajax form redirect to another url

Tags: ajax, forms, redirect

i want to redirect to another url when the form is submitted how can i do it
i am new to ajax so please tell where to add the code which can do it

here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm() {
if ($("#fields_fname").val() == "") {
    $("#fields_fname").focus();
    alert("The First Name field is required.");
return false;
}
if ($("#fields_lname").val() == "") {
    $("#fields_lname").focus();
    alert("The Last Name field is required.");
return false;
}
if ($("#fields_email").val() == "") {
    $("#fields_email").focus();
    alert("The Email field is required.");
return false;
}
if ($("#fields_phone").val() == "") {
    $("#fields_phone").focus();
    alert("The Phone field is required.");
return false;
}
if ($("#fields_zip").val() == "") {
    $("#fields_zip").focus();
    alert("The Postal Code field is required.");
return false;
}
if ($("#fields_suffix").val() == "") {
$("#fields_suffix").focus();
    alert("The 'I'm Interested In' field is required.");
    return false;
}
$.ajax({
    url: 'zohoprocess.php', 
    type:'POST',
    data:$('#ContactForm').serialize(), 
    success: function(){
       $(".form_result").html('Form 1 submitted successfully');
       $.ajax({
            url: 'https://app.icontact.com/icp/signup.php', 
            type:'POST',
            data:$('#ContactForm').serialize(), 
            success: function(){
               $(".form_result").html('Form 2 submitted successfully');
            },
            error:function(){
              alert("success");
              $(".form_result").html('');
              return false;
            } 
            });
    },
    error:function(){
      alert("failure");
      $(".form_result").html('');
      return false;
    } 
    });
return false;
}
</script>
<form id="ContactForm">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://tennispronow.com/thanks.html">
<input type="hidden" name="errorredirect" value="http://www.icontact.com/www/signup/error.html">

<div id="SignUp">
<table width="260" class="signupframe" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
  <td valign="top" align="right">
    <span class="required">*</span>Email
  </td>
  <td align="left">
    <input type="text" name="fields_email" id="fields_email">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="top" align="right">
    <span class="required">*</span>First Name
  </td>
  <td align="left">
    <input type="text" name="fields_fname" id="fields_fname">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="top" align="right">
    <span class="required">*</span>Last Name
  </td>
  <td align="left">
    <input type="text" name="fields_lname" id="fields_lname">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="top" align="right">
    <span class="required">*</span>What Level Player are you?
  </td>
  <td align="left">
    <select name="fields_prefix" id="fields_prefix">
      <option></option>
      <option value="Beginner">Beginner</option>
      <option value="Upper Beginner">Upper Beginner</option>
      <option value="Intermediate">Intermediate</option>
      <option value="Advanced">Advanced</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="top" align="right">
    <span class="required">*</span>I am Interested in:
  </td>
  <td align="left">
    <select name="fields_suffix" id="fields_suffix">
      <option></option>
      <option value="Private Lessons">Private Lessons</option>
      <option value="Lessons & Equipment">Lessons & Equipment</option>
      <option value="Classes">Classes</option>
      <option value="Equipment">Equipment</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="top" align="right">
    <span class="required">*</span>Other Info:
  </td>
  <td align="left">
    <input type="text" name="fields_fax"  id="fields_fax">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="top" align="right">
    <span class="required">*</span>Phone
  </td>
  <td align="left">
    <input type="text" name="fields_phone" id="fields_phone">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="top" align="right">
    <span class="required">*</span>Postal Code
  </td>
  <td align="left">
    <input type="text" name="fields_zip" id="fields_zip">
  </td>
</tr>
<input type="hidden" name="listid" value="42670">
<input type="hidden" name="specialid:42670" value="D1CQ">
<input type="hidden" name="clientid" value="860526">
<input type="hidden" name="formid" value="4668">
<input type="hidden" name="reallistid" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="doubleopt" value="0">
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td><span class="required">*</span> = Required Field</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
 <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onClick="return submitForm()">
</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <div class="form_result"> </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

please check it dont know what to write more

Answer (score 0):

Just add action attribute to the form tag.